# Legend en Matplotlib (mpatches.Patch)

Tags: matplotlib

Estoy haciendo un grafica con matplotlib, mi grafica se arma con informacion de un df y estoy tratando de poner una legend en base a info de otro df, llego sin problemas usando un id, ahora mi legend es un mpatches.Patch (Pone el dato y adelante un cuadrado de color como item).
No encontre como simplicicar esto ya que lo unico que se repite son los labels, se puede hacer menos truculento? Anda pero lo veo y no puedo dejar de pensar "Esto esta mal"

```
    age = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Age: ' + str(int(data.Age[row])))
    posit = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Position: ' + data.Position[row])
    numb = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Jersey Number: ' + str(int(data.Jersey_Number[row])))
    height = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Height: ' + data.Height[row])
    weight = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Weight: ' + data.Weight[row])
    body = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Body Type: ' + data.Body_Type[row])
    foot = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Preferred Foot: ' + data.Preferred_Foot[row])
    value = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label= 'Value: ' + data.Value[row])
    wage = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Wage: ' + data.Wage[row])
    loaned = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Loaned From: ' + data.Loaned_From[row])
    joinde = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Joined: ' + data.Joined[row])
    contract = mpatches.Patch(color= color_annotate, label='Contract Valid: ' + data.Contract_Valid[row])

ax.legend(handles=[age, posit, numb, height, weight, body, foot, value, wage, loaned, joinde, contract], bbox_to_anchor=(1.30, 1.08), 
          loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
```

Como ven creo cada uno de los mpatches.Patch y dsp los meto dentro del handles del legend, pero es siempre lo mismo solo que cambia el label, probe con array y diccionarios dentro del label pero no puedo hacer que los tome y reducir todo ese codigo repetido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude reducir el código basandome en [esta repuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44113141/6388106) hasta llegar a esto:
Si alguien tiene una respuesta mejor, los leo. Muchas gracias.

```
    labels = ['Age: ' + str(int(data.Age[row])), 'Position: ' + data.Position[row], 
    'Jersey Number: ' + str(int(data.Jersey_Number[row])), 'Height: ' + 
    data.Height[row],'Weight: ' + data.Weight[row],  'Body Type: ' + 
    data.Body_Type[row], 'Preferred Foot: ' + data.Preferred_Foot[row], 'Value: ' + 
    data.Value[row],'Wage: ' + data.Wage[row], 'Loaned From: ' + 
    data.Loaned_From[row], 'Joined: ' + data.Joined[row], 'Contract Valid: ' + 
    data.Contract_Valid[row]]

    patches = [plt.plot([],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[], marker="s", ms=10, 
    ls="", mec=None, color= color_annotate, label="{:s}".format(labels[i])) 
    [0] for i in range(len(labels))]

    ax.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.30, 1.08), 
          loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)

    print(labels)
```

> ['Age: 31', 'Position: RF', 'Jersey Number: 10', "Height: 5'7",
>   'Weight: 159lbs', 'Body Type: Normal', 'Preferred Foot: Left', 'Value:
>   €110.5M', 'Wage: €565K', 'Loaned From: No data', 'Joined: Jul 1,
>   2004', 'Contract Valid: 2021']

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]